# AttributeError: 'EventualResult' object has no attribute 'status_code'

Tags: django, twisted

I am running a django view using crochet library, however I am getting . I though is really simple, but with none experience I dont know how to solve it

```
Internal Server Error: /clocking/request/send_fence_to_device/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 29, in process_response
    if (response.status_code == 404 and
AttributeError: 'EventualResult' object has no attribute 'status_code'
ERROR:django.request:Internal Server Error: /clocking/request/send_fence_to_device/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 29, in process_response
    if (response.status_code == 404 and
AttributeError: 'EventualResult' object has no attribute 'status_code'
{'answer': 'ok'}
```

**My code view**

```
@run_in_reactor
def send_fence_to_device (request):
    device_id = request.GET['device_id']
    fence_id = request.GET['fence_id']
    fnc = Fence.objects.get(id=fence_id)
    dev = Device.objects.get(id=device_id)
    try:
        devLog = dev.devicelog_set.filter(device_id=device_id, status = True).order_by('created').reverse()[:1].all()[0]
    except:
        print "error"
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(0), mimetype='application/json')
    params = simplejson.loads(fnc.other)
    lttdlgtd = simplejson.loads(fnc.points)
    strCommand = ".geo.%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s*" % (params['identificator'], fnc.name[:4], round(float(lttdlgtd[0][0]), 4), round(float(lttdlgtd[0][1]), 4), round(float(fnc.radius), 4), params['time_to_arrive'], params['fence_class'], params['tolerance'], 1)
    print strCommand
    creator = ClientCreator(reactor, AMP)
    cmmdDeferred = creator.connectTCP('127.0.0.1', 8750)
    def connected(protocol):
        return protocol.callRemote(
            AmpProcessor,
            proto=str('TELCOMIP'),
            imei=str(devLog.ip),
            ip=str(devLog.ip),
            port=str(devLog.port),
            cmmd=str(strCommand)
            )
    cmmdDeferred.addCallback(connected)
    #def processed(result):
    #    print result
    #cmmdDeferred.addCallback(processed)
    def done(result):
        reactor.stop()
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(result), mimetype='application/json')
    cmmdDeferred.addCallback(done)
    #return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(1), mimetype='application/json')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is factory the the django function is two separated function, one that is the common function y one the twisted function, and the twisted will run in the reactor and the django function will call it using the .wait method

```
def view_function (request):
    one = request.GET['one']
    two = request.GET['two']
    result = sendMessage(one, two)
    try:
        answer = result.wait(timeout=None)
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(answer['answer']), mimetype='application/json')
    except TimeoutError:
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(-1), mimetype='application/json')

@run_in_reactor    
def twisted_function (_one, _two):
    def connected(protocol):
        return protocol.callRemote(
            RemoteFunction,
            one=_one,
            two=_two
            )
    return ClientCreator(reactor, AMP).connectTCP('127.0.0.1', 8750).addCallback(lambda p: connected(p))
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't call `wait` on the result of `send_fence_to_device` anywhere.

Also, `send_fence_to_device` still calls `reactor.stop` which will probably break things.

Maybe it would be useful to try a simpler example first - such as the example given on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crochet.  Once you understand what each part of that is doing, you might have an easier time debugging your more complicated application.

Also, your question doesn't include an http://sscce.org/ so all of this is guesswork (informed by some experience with Twisted, at least, but none with Crochet).  In the future, consider posting an http://sscce.org/ with your question so that less guesswork is required to given an answer.  You might find more people willing to offer answers if you do this, and the answers might be better quality.